# Convert dictionary to multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a dictionary to a multi-dimensional array. This because I want to paste the key's and values to a range in an Excel sheet. I did this before with other arrays with the following code:

```
shXL3.Range("A1", "B" & policies.GetLength(0)).Value = policies
```

The **policies** dictionary variable has been filled during a while loop that was reading file lines. How do I convert the **policies** variable to a multidimensional array so the code above will work?

Comment: have you tried iterating it?  It is just a collection

Comment: I can do that, but it feels a bit wrong...

Comment: You can also get both the Keys and Values to an array of there own, which could allow you to pass them in two steps - Keys to RangeA, values to RangeB

Comment: You mean using CopyTo a one-dimensional array?

Comment: No need to copy at all: `keys = myDictionary.Keys.ToArray`  you could use ToArray in your range paste code without a temp array.  You only need a 2D array because of the way your question is posed